# uiswitch and UItableview

Tags: iphone, uitableview, iphone-sdk-3.0

Hi
I was just going through the controls called tableview and uiswitch i added the uiswitch control inside the table view cell with the help of the code given below

```
cell.accessoryView = objswitch;
```

Now what i wanted is that my tableviewcell text must change to on or off as per the value change event of the switch so i wrote a function which looks like this

```
-(void)changetext
{
    if(objswitch.on)
    {
        str = @"ON";
    }
    else
    {
        str = @"Off";
    }
}
```

where str is an object of NSString class...

and i have wrote a block of code in the init method

```
[objswitch addTarget:self action:@selector(changetext) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

and in the cell for row at index path function i have done this

```
cell.text = str;
```

but still i dont know what i am doing wrong the table text is not changing, please help me out

Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Guys am really sorry for this as i got the solution to my own question, what i did was

```
 -(void)changetext
{
    if(objswitch.on)
    {
        str = @"ON";
    }
    else
    {
        str = @"Off";
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData]; //forgot to add this line
}
```